# Upgrading a Python 3 virtual environment

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have installed Python 3.5.1 on top of 3.5.0 and I now want to update a virtual environment to use 3.5.1 but I can find no easy way to to this. It looks as if I will have to delete the virtual environment and then rebuild it with the new version of Python. Does anyone have a simpler way of doing this?

Comment: A minor update like that (z in version x.y.z) should not require doing anything -- the virtualenv contains a symlink to the system python3.5 executable which will have been replaced. For bigger updates (x or y in version x.y.z) I usually just delete the environment, recreate it for the new version and then `pip install -r requirements.txt`

Comment: As the previous change, binary for python will be updated for minor versions. You can recreate it if you are not sure you can user the -p flag to select your python when creating a new virtualenv.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a minor upgrade (3.5.0 -> 3.5.1 or more generally, where only `z` in `x.y.z` is changing), you should not need to do anything.

The virtualenv, in its `bin` subdirectory, has a symlink to the system Python executable like so:

```
python -> python3.5
python3 -> python3.5
python3.5 -> /usr/bin/python3.5
```

Since `/usr/bin/python3.5` is replaced when you upgrade from 3.5.0 to 3.5.1, the virtualenv will automatically use the new Python version.

If you’re doing a more major upgrade (`x` or `y` in `x.y.z`), you’ll need to upgrade the virtualenv.

If you’re using the [built-in `pyvenv` command](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/venv.html) (introduced in Python 3.3), it has an `--upgrade` flag:

> Upgrade the environment directory to use this
>   version of Python, assuming Python has been upgraded in-place.

… which should do the trick. Note that the `pyvenv` command is being replaced with `python3 -m venv` in Python 3.6.

If you’re using the `virtualenv` package rather than the built-in command, the most straightforward way to do this is to delete the virtualenv and recreate it with the new version of Python, and then run `pip install -r requirements.txt`.

This assumes you have a `requirements.txt` file for your project. You can create one of these files, which lists all the packages installed in your virtualenv, by running `pip freeze --local > requirements.txt` before upgrading Python and recreating the virtualenv.

Comment: This did the trick nicely, thank you!

Comment: I do not have either a `requirements.txt` file or a time machine to let me create one before doing the upgrade. Do you know if there’s any better option than downgrading, getting the requirements file, and re-upgrading?